# How classify new entries in python having classified knowledge base

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a set of vectors, in python, composing my knowledge base, for example:

```
 KB=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1],[4,3,1,2],[5,4,3,5]]
```

Now I computed the cluster for KB, using:

```
 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
 model=KMeans(n_clusters=3)
 model.fit(KB)
```

Now I have a new entry (could I have more than one),

```
 A=[3,2,1,3]
```

and I would know which is the cluster that best fits *A* with respect to the cluster computed above, then exploiting the KB.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's : `user_sub_for_k` ?

Comment: it is a typo, sorry. I correct the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
KB=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1],[4,3,1,2],[5,4,3,5]]
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
model=KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(KB)
A=[3,2,1,3]
l = model.predict([A])
print model.labels_, l

centers = model.cluster_centers_.copy()
print centers
```

In order you model to be 'fit', i join two lines.
I then use the method predict to .. predict.
I also print the labels for each example that were use in the model.

**Edit** Add plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
# Compute the distances vector to vector
d = numpy.array([[numpy.sum(KBi - cj) for KBi in KB] for cj in centers])
print d
# for cluster 0 and 1
plt.scatter(d[0], d[1])
plt.pause(10)
```

Comment: Perfect, absolutely great. I have a last question. If  I would plot the data to show the KB and the A vector position in a 2D plot with relative clusters, How could I do?

Comment: You should use `matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: I'm sorry. But, could you please provide an example?

Comment: Done in the answer (more readible)